# Приложение вылетает с NullPointerException при переходе на MapFragment на эмуляторе

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api

Возникла необходимость интегрировать в проект карты google, накидал по руководству google MapFragment, до этого с картами google дел не имел, проверил вчера на телефоне(Samsung Galaxy S4) - фрагмент открывается и корректно отображает карту. GoogleMaps API на сайте google активирован, ключ Api в манифесте прописан. Activity, в котором запускаются фрагменты, наследуется от AppCompatActivity. При попытке перехода на фрагмент с картой на встроенном в студию эмуляторе(Nexus 4 21 API(with GoogleAPIs) и Nexus 4 23 API(with GoogleAPIs), приложение вылетает.

**Вопрос: Что можно предпринять, чтобы фрагмент с картами корректно запускался и отображал карты на эмуляторе?**

Прилагаю стактрейс ошибки, полный код фрагмента, и частично лэйаут, манифест и Build.gradle.

**Cтактрейс ошибки**:

```
12-07 11:15:09.290 2318-2318/xx.xxx.xxx W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8185480
12-07 11:15:09.290 2318-2318/xx.xxx.xxx W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8185480
12-07 11:15:09.290 2318-2318/xx.xxx.xxx W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8185480
12-07 11:15:09.290 2318-2318/xx.xxx.xxx W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8185480
12-07 11:15:09.290 2318-2318/xx.xxx.xxx W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8185480
12-07 11:15:09.290 2318-2318/xx.xxx.xxx W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8185480
12-07 11:15:09.300 2318-2318/xx.xxx.xxx W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8185480
12-07 11:15:09.300 2318-2318/xx.xxx.xxx W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8185480
12-07 11:15:09.300 2318-2318/xx.xxx.xxx W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8185480
12-07 11:15:09.320 2318-2318/xx.xxx.xxx D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-07 11:15:09.320 2318-2318/xx.xxx.xxx E/ACRA: ACRA caught a NullPointerException for xx.xxx.xxx
                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                            at xx.xxx.xxx.courier.OrdersFragmentMap.onCreateView(OrdersFragmentMap.java:45)
                                                            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
                                                            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
                                                            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                                                            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
                                                            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

---

**Код фрагмента с картами**:

```
package xx.xxx.xxx.courier;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import xx.xxx.xxx.R;

public class OrdersFragmentMap extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public static OrdersFragmentMap newInstance() { return  new OrdersFragmentMap(); }

    public OrdersFragmentMap() {  }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courier_fragment_map, container, false);
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.506);

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Sydney").snippet(
                "The most populous city in Australia.").position(sydney));

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

**Лэйаут**, содержащий MapFragment(фрагмент):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              tools:context="xx.xxx.xxx.CourierActivity"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
   <!-- other elements -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Манифест**(фрагмент):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xx.xxx.xxx" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.demomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.demomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSRVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 <!-- To using maps -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:name=".xxx"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_pink"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:name=".service.ServerService" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSy*****************VJifvg4M4"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

         <!-- other elements -->

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Build.gradle**(фпагмент):

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.nbsp:library:1.01'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.7.0-RC.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Гапсы на эмуляторе стоят?

Comment: Т.е. на реальном девайсе этот код работает, а на эмуляторе крашится?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Установил на эмулятор с 23 API com.android.vending.apk (v6.0.0) и com.google.android.gms.apk(v8.3.01), теперь перед вылетом эмулятора пишет: "unfortunately google services has stopped", то е самое пишет при запуске магазина

Comment: @BORSHEVIK именно.

Comment: Ставьте Genymotion. С ним таких проблем не будет

Comment: и вот эта строчка судя по всему у вас лишняя compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

Comment: @АндроидАндроид поставил genymotion, создал проект с шаблоном MapsActivity, сгенерировал ключ - все работает, карта на эмуляторе есть. Включаю свой проект - карта не отображается, даже если вставить туда, такую же активность как в стандартном шаблоне   ' 12-10 19:00:37.804 4967-4980/su.u_c.miracleshop E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
12-10 19:00:37.804 4967-4967/su.u_c.miracleshop I/fd: Started server for package su.u_c.miracleshop
12-10 19:00:37.808 4967-4980/su.u_c.miracleshop E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled '    думаю все из-за этой ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему следующим образом. Во-первых изменил код класса фрагмента, чтобы приложение не вылетало на версиях API 21 и выше:

```
public class OrdersFragmentMap extends Fragment
        implements OnMapReadyCallback, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    ArrayList<Order> freeOrders =  new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Order> myOrders = new ArrayList<>();
    private FragmentActivity myContext;


    public static OrdersFragmentMap newInstance() { return  new OrdersFragmentMap(); }

    public OrdersFragmentMap() {  }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courier_fragment_map, container, false);
        FragmentManager fm = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.506);

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Sydney").snippet(
                "The most populous city in Australia.").position(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
```

Метод onAttach() является устаревшим и я использую его временно только для того, чтобы запустить android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager в AppCompatActivity.

Во-вторых создал шаблон MapActivity, для этого в корне проекта щелкнуть правой клавишей мыши, выбрать new>Google>GoogleMapsActivity. Из трех созданных файлов оставил только res/values/google_maps_api.xml(debug), скопировал из него ссылку для генерации ключа, которая находится в комментарии, перешел по ней в браузере, создал ключ и все заработало. Самое странное, что до этого вводил тот же фингерпринт и имя пакета. Такие вот дела.

А на Galaxy S4 API работал, видимо, в обход защиты Google, так как запросов в консоли разработчика во время работы приложения не было.